# Help me to find name of this script font

Tags: font-identification, script-typeface

I'm trying to find the font used in the image below. I tried in the myfont and whatfontis websites but did not find it. Can anybody can help me to find the name of the font?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried converting the image to monochrome and adjusting levels so that the background is filtered out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

[image]

It's Dark Larch Regular. The letter spacing seems to be increased or a slice is edited off. The latter is more probable because at least I can see remnants due the sloppy slicing.

The image was cleaned by adjusting the yellow hue to white and the brown to black. No use to try the desaturating or the magic wand at first. Only a couple of dots needed the eraser.

Comment: Great Thanks...May i know how did you find and which website

Comment: @atek  Font Squirrel Matcherator https://www.fontsquirrel.com  found the font. Myfont Whatthefont did not. The method is inserted to the answer.